# Using json blob field attributes in MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7 and have a table with following schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key',
  `created_by` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `metadata` blob COMMENT 'to capture the custom metadata',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

And the sample row data for the table looks like this

```
1234,user1,open,"{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}",2021-05-18 16:01:25
```

I want to select rows from this table based on the keys in json blob field `metadata`; for example, let's say where `key1 = 'value1'`. So I tried something like this

```
select * from `test` where metadata->>"$.key1" = "value1";
```

But I got this error `Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'`. So I casted it to json first by something like below

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(CAST(metadata as JSON), "$") as meta from test;
```

The problem is this returns `base64` encoded string and when I try to decode the same using `FROM_BASE64` like below I get `null` values in the column.

```
select FROM_BASE64(JSON_EXTRACT(CAST(metadata as JSON), "$")) as meta from test;
```

So I think I have two problems here: the first one being how to decode the base64 encoded data which I get after casting blob as json, and second how to filter the rows based on keys in the metadata field.

I do feel this as a design error where the most ideal data type should have been `json` but since this is how it is now, I need some way to workaround this.

## Edit

I also tried following as suggested in one of the comments

```
select cast(convert(cast(metadata as char) using utf8) as json) from test;
```

but I get this error

```
Data truncation: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_json: "Missing a name for object member." at position 1
```

Is there any way I can work around this ?

Comment: You have made a database design error. Since 5.7.8 a native JSON data type is supported. Try to:

select cast(convert(cast(metadata as char) using utf8) as json) from test;

Comment: @YuriyPiskunov I 100% second your opinion here, actually someone else designed the database and I realise this is a design issue but still wanted to know if there is a workaround for this. Also how do I use this converted json in `where` clause ?

Comment: Also this throws me this error `Data truncation: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_json: "Missing a name for object member." at position 1.`